# How to simplify my bash code?

Tags: bash

I've write the following code in bash, this code tends to print a matrix of 200x13 random numbers (we have 200 line printed with 13 numbers per line). I want this code to be more flexible such that one can change size of the matrix printed (number of line and number of number per line) without re-write the code

```
for (( k = 0; k < 200; k++  ))
do

    echo $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) $(( $RANDOM - 16384 ))

done
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to change the printing of the columns to another for-loop:

```
for (( k = 0; k < 200; k++  ))
do
 for (( j = 0; j < 3; j++))
 do
    echo -n $(( $RANDOM - 16384 ))" "  # print your random number

 done

 echo     # print newline 
done
```

Then, you can parametrize your k max and j max:

```
rows=200   # set the number of rows
cols=3    # set the number of columns

for (( k = 0; k < $rows; k++  ))
do
   for (( j = 0; j < $cols; j++))
   do
       echo -n $(( $RANDOM - 16384 ))" "   

   done

   echo
done
```

Comment: I think you mean parameterize rows/cols (of course, just semantics, as you're referring to the same thing.)

Answer (score 1):

To do this simply, just add a nested loop to repeat the columns.

Also in bash you can do a for loop with brace expansion ...

```
for a in {1..200}
do # Rows...
    for b in {1..13}
    do # Columns...
        echo -n "$(( $RANDOM - 16384 )) " 
        # -n suppresses newlines
    done
    echo 
    # do newline at the end of the row.
done
```

If the script was going to become more complicated. I'd suggest abstracting the script into functions.

```
function printRandomNumber() { 
   seed={1:-16384}
   echo -n "$(( $RANDOM - $seed ))" 
}

function printRandomMatrix() {
    rows={1:-200} # default 200 if not set.
    cols={2:-13} # default 13 if not set.

    for a in {1..$rows}
    do
        for b in {1..$cols}
        do  
            printRandomNumber
        done
        echo 
    done
}
```

Then call it with

```
printRandomMatrix 
# print the default row/column matrix.

printRandomMatrix 10 10
# print a matrix of 10 by 10.
```

This way you can more easily maintain the script and adapt to changes, e.g. if you needed to format the output using `printf` as shown in D.Shawley's answer. Of course you may want a variety of possible visual formatting (left/right column alignment etc.) these can be achieved with a variety of tricks... [More on shell text formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199843/bourne-shell-left-right-justify)

Comment: I suggest we clean up the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a [shell function](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) and use [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) instead of `echo`.

```
printMatrix() {
  cols=${1:-13}
  rows=${2:-200}
  for (( i=0; i<$rows; i++ ))
  do
    for (( j=0; j<$cols; j++ ))
      printf "%13d" $(( $RANDOM - 16384))
    done
    echo
  done
}

printMatrix # will print 200x13 matrix
printMatrix 5 10  # with print 10x5 matrix
```

Since this is in a shell function, you can source the function definition and call it directly from the shell.  If the function is in a file named *shfuncs*, then you can source it and run it like follows:

```
bash$ source shfuncs
bash$ printMatrix 3 2
11118        31           -9753        
-13700       -12008       -1779 
bash$
```